# How to get file location from a drive with SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, file, sql-server-2012, file-access

How can I get a file from my `C:` drive with SQL Server?

I tried `host_name()` and it did not work

Answer (score 0):

```
EXEC xp_dirtree 'C:\', 1, 1
```

That will give you a list of the folders and/or files in your C:\ drive. 
http://www.patrickkeisler.com/2012/11/how-to-use-xpdirtree-to-list-all-files.html

Comment: Of course, that is the `C:` drive on the **machine where SQL Server runs** - if that's a remote server, you'll get the directories and files **from that remote server** - not from your local PC's `C:` drive .....